# Is leaflet maps can work only with integer zoom level?

Tags: leaflet

I have tried using zoomSnap = 1 and most of the times(95%) i get an integer, however sometimes the zoom sets to be a fragment.
is there a way using leaflet configuration to prevent getting by all means fragment zoom property?